# viewpager using JSON

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have written code for image slider but i use drawable images..

Actually i want to know, How to use online images in slideshow instead of 
drawables...please help me with complete code as i am new to android..

```
public class DealsFragment extends Fragment {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


public static DealsFragment newInstance() {
    DealsFragment fragment = new DealsFragment();
    return fragment;
}


public DealsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deals, container, false);



    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageOneDeals.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageTwoDeals.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageThreeDeals.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

ImageOneDeals.java

```
public class ImageOneDeals extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(container==null){
        return null;

    }
    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.image1_deals,container,false);
}

}
```

ImagePagerAdapter.java

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;


public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments){
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.fragments=fragments;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

Comment: The short answer is: use an image loader and supply it (at least) the url of the remote image and a view to load it into. There are plenty libraries out there that allow you to do this, including Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader, Fresco etc.

Comment: can you please send me some kind of link for where i can see..how it works

Comment: Sorry, no. I imagine you're perfectly capable of performing a Google search yourself. Heck, the answers below already show the gist of it...

Answer (score 0):

Your Deal Fragment:-

```
public class DealFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_view_pager, container, false);

            new GetUserImage().execute();    //run your webservices here
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public class GetUserImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            postUserImageData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //save your data in a list
            // set Adapter after you get data from webservices
            mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slidePager);
            ImagePagerAdapter viewImagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), TotalCount, imagearr);
            mPager.setAdapter(viewImagePagerAdapter);
            mPager.getCurrentItem();
        }

        public void postUserImageData() {

        }
    }
}
```

your Adapter:-

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfItemSize;
    List<UserImage> arr1;

    public ImagePagerAdapter (FragmentManager childFragmentManager, int num_pages, List<UserImage> customMessageListView) {
        super(childFragmentManager);
        this.numOfItemSize = num_pages;
        this.arr1 = customMessageListView;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        ImageOneDeals  userImageDetailFragment = new ImageOneDeals ();
        UserImage sc = arr1.get(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ProfilePic", sc.ProfilePic);
        bundle.putString("Work", sc.Work);
        bundle.putString("BirthTime", sc.BirthTime);
        bundle.putString("Message", sc.Message);

        userImageDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return userImageDetailFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfItemSize;
    }
}
```

your ImageOneDeals :-

```
public class ImageOneDeals  extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Title = getArguments().getString("ProfilePic");
        BirthTime = getArguments().getString("BirthTime");
        Work = getArguments().getString("Work");
        Message = getArguments().getString("Message");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_user_image, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initialiseViews();

    }

    public void initialiseViews() {
        ImageView imgDetails = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.UserimageView);
        TextView usrname = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.userName);
        TextView usrwork = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.userWork);
        //   imgLoader.DisplayImage(Title,imgDetails);
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(Title)
                .placeholder( R.mipmap.add_photo)
                .error( R.mipmap.add_photo)
                .into(imgDetails);
        usrname.setText(Message);
        usrwork.setText(Work);
    }
}
```

Comment: onPostExecute load your webservices and get imageurl